# "Query String" inside URL segments?

Tags: html, url, uri

Take the example question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563957/https-url-path-and-query-string`.

As you can see, we have the segment `/questions` followed by what I'm assuming is the question ID, `/3563957`. In my head, this would indicate a folder structure like:

```
.
└── questions/
    └── 3563957
```

However, I can't imagine a directory is being generated for each question. To me, this seems like a query string that is being used as a URL segment. How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished on the server side. When the server sees the request, it likely doesn't treat the url like a directory. This can be accomplished many different ways depending on what you are using for your server.

Comment: I have experience with both asp.net and php, do you have any idea how I could locate an example of these being implemented in either of those environments?

Comment: @NewWebDev I don't have much experience in those areas but I'm sure you could find some online.